# How do I format html code to have indents and custom spacing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that displays XML code.  How do I format the text so it has proper spacing and proper newlines?  In essence I want to prettify the xml.  I have a plunkr that displays the info:

http://tinyurl.com/ovmguoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add in your css :

```css
prettify {
  white-space: pre;
}

prettify > .pln:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

this will display your XML well formatted.

Comment: Been pulling my hair out on this one...thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

your code removes the inner `<pre>` tag,

either surround prettyfy with pre or use some fance css on prettyfy